# Cadastrar dados do datagridview em uma tabela no banco de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio

Fala galera boa tarde! 
Estou com um problema em fazer uma inserção de dados apresentado ao meu datagridview.

Eu tenho uma tabela chamada Eventos, e nela consta todos meus registros, eu criei uma outra tabela com os mesmo campos, para que fosse baixados os eventos quando a data estiver expirada.

o problema é o seguinte... quando eu faço a inserção dos dados apresentados da primeira tabela jogando eles para a tabela eventos baixados, os dados duplica, ou seja ele esta pegando tanto o primeiro id quando os demais.
Obs:(Estou selecionando os dados da linha do datagridview através de um menu e dando um click.)
segue a imagem.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue meu codigo

```
private void BaixarDadosAgenda()
    {
        try
        {
            if (DGW_Agenda.Rows.Count > 1)
            {
                cg.con = new SqlConnection(cn.DBconn);
                string cb = "INSERT INTO Eventos_Baixados VALUES (@Nome, @Endereco, @Quadra, @Lote, @Telefone, @Celular, @Data, @Hora, @Email, @Observacao, @Locacao, @Evento, @Estado)";
                cg.con.Open();
                cg.cmd = new SqlCommand(cb);
                cg.cmd.Connection = cg.con;
                for (int i = 0; i <= DGW_Agenda.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {       
                    DGW_Agenda.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    DGW_Agenda.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
                    DGW_Agenda.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
                    DGW_Agenda.MultiSelect = false;
                    cg.cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Nome"].Value);
                    cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Endereco", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Endereco"].Value);
                    cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quadra", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Quadra"].Value);
                    cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lote", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Lote"].Value);
                    cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefone", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Telefone"].Value);
                    cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Celular", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Celular"].Value);
                    cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Data"].Value);
                    cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hora", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Hora"].Value);
                    cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Email"].Value);
                    cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Observacao", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Observacao"].Value);
                    cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Locacao", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Locacao"].Value);
                    cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Evento", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Evento"].Value);
                    cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estado", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Estado"].Value);
                    cg.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DGW_Agenda.Rows.Clear();

                }
                cg.con.Close();
                st1 = Lbl_Usuario.Text;
                st2 = "Nova Locacão Baixada '" + TB_Nome.Text;
                cf.LogFunc(st1, DateTime.Now, st2);
                LogEvento.GravarLog("'Locação Baixada com Sucesso! :  = '" + TB_Nome.Text + "'Usuário'" + Lbl_Usuario.Text.ToString());
                Reset();
                BTN_Cadastrar.Enabled = false;

                MessageBox.Show("Locação Baixada Com Sucesso !", "Locação", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void BT_BaixaAgenda_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (MessageBox.Show("Deseja dar baixa nessa Locação?", "Aviso do Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {

            BaixarDadosAgenda();
        }

    }
```

Desde de já agradeço pela força!

Comment: Tu podes seleccionar mais de uma linha ?

Comment: Não! a ideia é selecionar uma linha por vez. eu fiz até um teste no minha rotina do meu for deixando ela assim.                                                            for (int i = 0; i <= DGW_Agenda.SelectedRows.Count - 1; i++)                               Porem sem sucesso!

Comment: Com o for não tem como funcionar

Answer (score 0):

O teu erro foi você criar o loop, não há necessidade de usares um loop se pretendes pegar uma linha, ele está a fazer a iteração e está a inserir todas as linhas na base de dados.

A solução seria assim:

```
try
    {
        if (DGW_Agenda.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
          if (DGW_Agenda.SelectedRows.Count > 0) // Para assegurar que existe linha selecionada
             {
            cg.con = new SqlConnection(cn.DBconn);
            string cb = "INSERT INTO Eventos_Baixados VALUES (@Nome, @Endereco, @Quadra, @Lote, @Telefone, @Celular, @Data, @Hora, @Email, @Observacao, @Locacao, @Evento, @Estado)";
            cg.con.Open();
            cg.cmd = new SqlCommand(cb);
            cg.cmd.Connection = cg.con;

               int i=DGW_Agenda.CurrentRow.Index; // pega o índice da linha selecionada
                DGW_Agenda.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                DGW_Agenda.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
                DGW_Agenda.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
                DGW_Agenda.MultiSelect = false;
                cg.cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Nome"].Value);
                cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Endereco", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Endereco"].Value);
                cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quadra", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Quadra"].Value);
                cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lote", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Lote"].Value);
                cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefone", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Telefone"].Value);
                cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Celular", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Celular"].Value);
                cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Data"].Value);
                cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hora", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Hora"].Value);
                cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Email"].Value);
                cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Observacao", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Observacao"].Value);
                cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Locacao", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Locacao"].Value);
                cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Evento", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Evento"].Value);
                cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estado", DGW_Agenda.Rows[i].Cells["Estado"].Value);
                cg.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                DGW_Agenda.Rows.Clear();


            cg.con.Close();
            st1 = Lbl_Usuario.Text;
            st2 = "Nova Locacão Baixada '" + TB_Nome.Text;
            cf.LogFunc(st1, DateTime.Now, st2);
            LogEvento.GravarLog("'Locação Baixada com Sucesso! :  = '" + TB_Nome.Text + "'Usuário'" + Lbl_Usuario.Text.ToString());
            Reset();
            BTN_Cadastrar.Enabled = false;

            MessageBox.Show("Locação Baixada Com Sucesso !", "Locação", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}

private void BT_BaixaAgenda_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    if (MessageBox.Show("Deseja dar baixa nessa Locação?", "Aviso do Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {

        BaixarDadosAgenda();
    }

}
```

Comment: Eu até entendi o que você quis dizer JoyPeter, o problema e que ele estava fazendo o insert de todos os registros, e o que eu preciso que seria um por vez de acordo com a data expirada.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema galera!

```html
 private void BaixarDadosAgenda()
        {
            try
            {
                var row = DGW_Agenda.CurrentRow;
                if (row != null)
                {
                    //ao meu ver essas configurações seriam ao carregar a tela
                    DGW_Agenda.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
                    DGW_Agenda.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
                    DGW_Agenda.MultiSelect = false;

                    cg.con = new SqlConnection(cn.DBconn);
                    string cb = "INSERT INTO Eventos_Baixados VALUES (@Nome, @Endereco, @Quadra, @Lote, @Telefone, @Celular, @Data, @Hora, @Email, @Observacao, @Locacao, @Evento, @Estado)";
                    cg.con.Open();
                    cg.cmd = new SqlCommand(cb);
                    cg.cmd.Connection = cg.con;
                    //for (int i = 0; i <= DGW_Agenda.SelectedRows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        cg.cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                        cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", row.Cells["Nome"].Value);
                        cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Endereco", row.Cells["Endereco"].Value);
                        cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quadra", row.Cells["Quadra"].Value);
                        cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lote", row.Cells["Lote"].Value);
                        cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefone", row.Cells["Telefone"].Value);
                        cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Celular", row.Cells["Celular"].Value);
                        cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", row.Cells["Data"].Value);
                        cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hora", row.Cells["Hora"].Value);
                        cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", row.Cells["Email"].Value);
                        cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Observacao", row.Cells["Observacao"].Value);
                        cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Locacao", row.Cells["Locacao"].Value);
                        cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Evento", row.Cells["Evento"].Value);
                        cg.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estado", row.Cells["Estado"].Value);
                        cg.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    cg.con.Close();

                    DGW_Agenda.Refresh();

                    st1 = Lbl_Usuario.Text;
                    st2 = "Nova Locacão Baixada '" + TB_Nome.Text;
                    cf.LogFunc(st1, DateTime.Now, st2);
                    LogEvento.GravarLog("'Locação Baixada com Sucesso! :  = '" + TB_Nome.Text + "'Usuário'" + Lbl_Usuario.Text.ToString());
                    Reset();
                    BTN_Cadastrar.Enabled = false;

                    MessageBox.Show("Locação Baixada Com Sucesso !", "Locação", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```